# How to mock clock.millis() in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-time

I have a code where I calculate the difference between current clock time and time saved in my db 
If difference between the two is greater than certain value then I return result accordingly.
For this case I am trying to write test but is facing problem to mock Clock.millis(). I have referred some answers but none worked for me can someone help me with that.[image: This is my function]

For my test I want to mock this clock.millis() function with a fixed value so that each time I run test it takes that value only.

Comment: Please post code as code and not as screenshot.

Comment: Take a look at these questions: [Mocking static methods with Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105403/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito) and [Mocking time in Java 8's java.time API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24491260/mocking-time-in-java-8s-java-time-api)

Comment: I found many solutions with PowerMockRunner but I have to use PandoraBootRunner can you help me in that

Comment: If you correctly wrote your code to use *injection*, so the [`Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) is injected, then you can unit test the code by passing in a different `Clock`, e.g. a [`fixed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html#fixed-java.time.Instant-java.time.ZoneId-) clock, and you wouldn't need to mock anything.

Answer (score 5):

A [`Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Clock.html) is meant for providing access to the current instant, date and time using a time-zone. You don't really need to mock it. As your class needs to obtain the current instant, so it should receive an instance of the [`Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Clock.html) in the constructor:

```java
public class FooService {

    private final Clock clock;

    public FooService(Clock clock) {
        this.clock = clock;
    }

    public boolean isLocked() {
        long differenceInSecond = (clock.millis() - this.getLockedAt()) / 1000;
        return differenceInSecond < 7200;
    }

    private long getLockedAt() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Then, in your test, you can use a [`fixed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Clock.html#fixed(java.time.Instant,java.time.ZoneId)) clock, which will always return the same instant:

```java
@Test
public void isLocked_shouldReturnTrue_whenDifferenceInSecondIsSmallerThan7200() {

    // Create a fixed clock, which will always return the same instant
    Instant instant = Instant.parse("2020-01-01T00:00:00.00Z");
    Clock clock = Clock.fixed(instant, ZoneOffset.UTC);

    // Create a service instance with the fixed clock
    FooService fooService = new FooService(clock);

    // Invoke the service method and then assert the result
    boolean locked = fooService.isLocked();
    assertThat(locked).isTrue();
}
```

---

In a Spring Boot application, you could expose a [`Clock`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Clock.html) as a [`@Bean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html):

```java
@Bean
public Clock clock() {
    return Clock.systemDefaultZone();
}
```

And then Spring will take care of injecting it into your service:

```java
@Service
public class FooService {

    private final Clock clock;

    public FooService(Clock clock) {
        this.clock = clock;
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap `Clock`into your own class, exposing `Clock.millis()` as a delegate. In your test you can then mock your wrapper and return whatever you like.

Comment: Can we not do mocking without creating a wrapper class ?