# How to mock system date with joda time

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-jodatime

I am writing a UI test for a flow that makes use of the current date to do some processing. Here's how I get the current date in my fragment:

```
val today = dateFormat.format(Date())
```

In my test, I want to use a fixed date. To this end, I decided to use [Joda time](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time). Here's how I implemented it in my test:

```
@Test
fun testAFlow() {

    // setting date to fixed value
    DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisFixed(1610248674000)

    // launching activity
    activityRule.launchActivity(Intent())

    // remainder flow
    ...
}
```

The test runs fine without breaking but the actual date is still being used instead of the mocked date. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get fixed date by calling of `currentTimeMillis` from `DateTimeUtils`

```
Log.d(BuildConfig.app_tag,"time " + DateTimeUtils.currentTimeMillis()); // output: current time millis

DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisFixed(1610248674000L);
    
Log.d(BuildConfig.app_tag,"time " + DateTimeUtils.currentTimeMillis()); // output: 1610248674000
```

the behavior of `System.currentTimeMillis()` will not be changed

Comment: Alright, thanks. How do I go about changing/mocking System.currentTimeMillis() then?

Comment: @TaslimOseni, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24491260/mocking-time-in-java-8s-java-time-api) could be helpful