# How do I simulate the passage of time with java.time.Clock?

Tags: java, mocking, java-time, jmock

Suppose I have this class, `ClassToBeTested`, where the time elapsed between its method calls are important. `foo` returns a different value depending on whether you have called `foo` in the last x hours.

The way I implemented this is to get the current `Instant` when `foo` is called, and compare it with the last `Instant` that `foo` is called, which I store in a field.

Since `ClassToBeTested` depends on the current time, I added a `Clock` field, which callers are required to pass in when they create a `ClassToBeTested`:

```
class ClassToBeTested {
    private final Clock clock;
    private Instant lastCalled;

    public ClassToBeTested(Clock clock) {
        this.clock = clock;
    }

    public String foo() {
        if (lastCalled == null || Duration.between(lastCalled, Instant.now(clock)).compareTo(Duration.ofHours(1)) >= 0) {
            lastCalled = Instant.now(clock);
            return "A";
        } else {
            lastCalled = Instant.now(clock);
            return "B";
        }
    }
}
```

When I am writing my tests though, I realised that there are no factory method that creates a mutable `Clock`. I tried to create my own mutable clock, so that my tests can look like this:

```
private final FakeClock fakeClock = new FakeClock();

@Test
public void fooReturnsAAfterAnHour() {
    var myInstance = new ClassToTest(fakeClock);
    assertThat(myInstance.foo(), is("A"));
    fakeClock.goForward1Hour(); // this mutates the clock, and changes what instant() will return
    assertThat(myInstance.foo(), is("A"))
}

@Test
public void fooReturnsBWithinAnHour() {
    var myInstance = new ClassToTest(fakeClock);
    assertThat(myInstance.foo(), is("A"));
    fakeClock.goForward30Minutes(); // this mutates the clock, and changes what instant() will return
    assertThat(myInstance.foo(), is("B"))
}
```

only to find that in the documentation, it says:

> All implementations that can be instantiated must be final, immutable and thread-safe.

So it seems like a mutable implementation of `Clock` is incorrect. But looking up posts on stack overflow, many suggest using a mutable clock ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56026271/5133585)). [Some](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44795939/5133585) also suggest mocking the `Clock` abstract class. When I tried that out, jMock (which is what I'm using) doesn't like it because `Clock` is not an interface. Apparently, [if I want to mock classes, I'd have to include another dependency](http://jmock.org/mocking-classes.html), which is mainly used for mocking legacy code. That doesn't sound appropriate for mocking `Clock` to me.

I can also add a setter for the `clock` field in `ClassToBeTested`, so that I can do:

```
myInstance.setClock(Clock.offset(clock, Duration.ofHours(1)));
```

to advance the time. But I think this breaks encapsulation.

And at this point, I'm out of ideas. What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `FakeClock` approach is fine.  That's the approach I'd use.

If you prefer to use an implementation from a library instead of your own, you could use [`MutableClock`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/MutableClock.html) from the [threeten-extra](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library.  That class was designed for exactly this use case.

The "immutable" requirement was [removed](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/commit/6c838c568c2c99145fd0ae8059de2b2865b65863) from the `Clock` class in Java 17.  It was removed not because of changes being made to `Clock`'s implementation, but because the requirement was harmfully restrictive (see your use case) while not serving a useful purpose.  So if you're using Java <17, I'd say it's safe to simply ignore that requirement.

Comment: It's nice to know that the immutable requirement is removed! I guess I should be checking more up-to-date docs. The thread-safe requirement has not been removed though, which means that I should still make the mutating methods `synchronized`.

Comment: I always wondered how `Clock.systemUTC()` was considered mutable. Right: all its fields are mutable. So to create an immutable clock which can be advanced: include a final field which holds a mutable object. This object returns your "time" and can be advanced. Stupid I know (and I see that `MutableClock` follows this approach); just go with a mutable clock and make sure you are using Atomic fields or proper synchronization.